# Jquery - Getting all content inside a DIV EXCEPT a particular object

Tags: jquery, html, exception

how do I get all content inside a DIV? I want to save all the code that exists within #wrapper DIV on my page. That is easy. But the thing is... how do I select all EXCEPT for one particular object (the image with "main" class).

You can see how it works here http://www.jsfiddle.net/8A27a/

This is what I have so far:

```
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="icon"><img src="http://www.yousendit.com/en_US/theme_default/images/g_logo_trans_110x63.gif"></div>
            <div class="icon"><img src="http://www.yousendit.com/en_US/theme_default/images/g_logo_trans_110x63.gif"></div>   
            <div class="icon"><img src="http://www.yousendit.com/en_US/theme_default/images/g_logo_trans_110x63.gif"></div>  
            <img class="main" src="http://afteramerica.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/061221225103_abraham_lincoln_lg1.jpg">
        </div>

        <input type="button" value="save" class="save">

    <script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
            $('.save').live('click', function() {
                var content = $('#wrapper').html();
                alert(content);
             });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only reliable way I can think of is to clone the DIV, remove the IMG tag and get the resulting HTML:

```
var e = $('#wrapper').clone();
$('img.main', e).remove();
alert(e.html());
```

Note that this can be inefficient for DIVs with a lot of content.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$('.save').live('click', function() {
    var content = $('#wrapper > *').not('img.main').clone();
    content = $('<div></div>').append(content);
    content = content.html();
    alert(content);
 });
```

[edit] improved example to match OP's example.

Comment: Hmm.. it seems ot be returning OBJECT OBJECT... can I add HTML() at the end of it?

Comment: yeah... sorry, I missed the context you were working within.  I just changed the example.  This works, but it uses `clone()`. I'll think on a solution that doesn't involve clone.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `.not` selector: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/